3D Plastic Effect on Custom Shape in TikZ
I'm trying to produce a 3D effect on a shape using the code below. The image on the left shows my current output, and the image on the right is a mockup of the effect I'm aiming for, which I created in MS Word. I'm looking for a shiny plastic button effect with light at the top and dark at the bottom. The MS Word mockup isn't perfect, and the 3D effect could be improved, but it gives the general idea. Hopefully TikZ can be used to produce a much better 3D effect. The image below is also a 3D effect that could work well.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue]
($ (0cm, 0cm) $) arc[start angle=180, end angle=90, radius=0.5cm]
-- ($ (0cm,0cm) + (5cm,0.5cm) $) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=0.5cm]
-- ($ (5.5cm,1.5cm) $) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=0.5cm]
-- ($ (0.5cm,2cm) $) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=0.5cm]
-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I've experimented with gradients and fades in TikZ to achieve something similar, but the shape still looks flat. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get that proper 3D appearance. What’s the best way to achieve a convincing 3D look in LaTeX? A similar question was asked here, however the shape is different and it still looks flat. I was hoping someone might be able to provide a better solution.

The normal way is to play with the keys
bottom color=cyan!55!blue, 
top color=cyan!11,
middle color=blue, 

For example:

\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[bottom color=cyan!55!blue, 
top color=cyan!11,
middle color=blue, 
]
($ (0cm, 0cm) $) arc[start angle=180, end angle=90, radius=0.5cm]
-- ($ (0cm,0cm) + (5cm,0.5cm) $) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=0.5cm]
-- ($ (5.5cm,1.5cm) $) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=0.5cm]
-- ($ (0.5cm,2cm) $) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=0.5cm]
-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks, but I'm not sure this looks very 3D. I've tried similar gradient effects myself and it always looks like flat. It never quite captures the darker lower side and slightly darker outline at the top. I've added another image to show the sort of thing that I think looks slightly better.

Aha, maybe I over-read that. So you could try to draw your 'thing' as a 3D-graph with with 3D-coordinates.
